# Web.config page - ASP.NET 3.5 error

Tags: asp.net, configuration, web-config

I have the following web.config page (My site is in ASP.NET 3.5):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="3.0"/>
    <pages validateRequest="false"/>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
  </system.web>
</configuratiotn>
```

The problem is that there is an error under the  `targetFramework` and the `requestValidationMode`.

But I get thie errors:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode. Note that names are case-sensitive features.
```

> Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework. Note that names are case-sensitive features.

My question is how can I fix this error?

Comment: check you application pool of your site is configured for .NET Framework Version. May be the target framework is less than 3.0

Answer (score 0):

`requestValidationMode` and `targetFramework` are .NET 4.0+ specific, so you can't use those in an ASP.NET 3.5 project.

Comment: Hi, thank you, but if I delete this parts I get error that says " The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?) "  What shold I do?

Comment: In the error bar, and in every C# page (in all the pages there are using system linq).